# Operator and operand don't agree can't find why

Tags: sml, ml

I'm working on this code and can't make it run. I've checked it few times and still can't figure out why it's not working.

```
fun date_to_string (date : (int * int * int)) =
  let
      val months = ["January", "February","March", "April",
                    "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
      fun get_nth (xs : string list, n : int) =
        if n=1
        then hd xs
        else get_nth(tl xs, n-1)
  in
      get_nth(months, Int.toString(#2 date)) ^ " " ^ Int.toString(#3 date) ^ ", " ^ Int.toString(#1 date)
  end
```

Here is what I get back when I try to run it:

[image]

Comment: You are applying `get_nth` to a pair of list and string, not list and int: `get_nth(months, Int.toString(#2 date))`. The result of `Int.toString` is not an int. You probably don't want to be using that function there at all. Also, there is a basis library function `List.nth` you may want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see an error of the form:

```
operator domain: <type1>
operand : <type2>
```

then it is saying that it is expecting something of type `<type1>`, but you are giving it something of type `<type2>`.  In your case, `get_nth` is expecting a tuple, where the first element is a list of strings and the second element is an int.  You are providing a tuple where the first element is a list of strings (which is correct), but your second argument is a string, which should be an int.  You are going to want to change

```
get_nth(months, Int.toString(#2 date))
```

to

```
get_nth(months, #2(date))
```

Comment: Good observation, I had totally forgot about it. Thank you